# Edit text UI is not proper in Oreo device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-8.0-oreo

I'm facing an issue in android oreo version .
The UI of `edittext` component is not proper in `oreo version` of android.

[image]

The same is working fine in all other versions.I have not updated app theme specific to `edittext`. Please help me resolve this issue.

The **code** is been updated with question for reference. PFA for image reference.
I have used 2 edittext with linearlayout.

Thanks.

```
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_spacing_small">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/signinUserNameWrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_extra_small">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/signinUserName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_extra_small"
                            android:hint="@string/signIn.username"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
                            android:textColor="@color/base_dark"
                            android:textColorHighlight="@color/base_dark"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/base_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:theme="@style/ComponentTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/signinPasswordWrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/signinPassword"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_spacing_extra_small"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_extra_small"
                            android:hint="@string/signIn.password"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
                            android:textColor="@color/base_dark"
                            android:textColorHighlight="@color/base_dark"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/base_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:theme="@style/ComponentTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/showPassword"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
                        android:text="@string/signIn.showPassword"
                        android:textColor="@color/base_dark"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        android:theme="@style/ComponentTheme" />

                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/handle_signin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        app:mrl_rippleBackground="@color/app_theme"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/base_light"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_spacing_small">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/login"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/view_spacing_extra_small"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_proceed" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your **`CODE`**

Comment: "is not proper" - what does this mean? What is not proper and how should it look like?

Comment: Please add your theme too, that @style/ComponentTheme is most likely the culprit

Comment: Finally found the solution, for v21/styles app theme was internally calling the **values/styles.xml** app theme.